# why ng-click is not working on ng-repeat elements?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I am trying to bind ng-click on ng-repeated elements and trying to show/hide a div. For a strange reason, its not working for me. Can any one please take a look ? Adding the fiddle link below

http://jsfiddle.net/uLujthsp/8/

```
<div data-ng-app="" ng-init="names=['Jani','Hege','Kai']">
  <p>Looping with ng-repeat:</p>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in names" ng-click="click!=click">
      {{ x }}
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div id="hiddenDiv" ng-class="{show:click}">Showing</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: see my answer may be it will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try `ng-click="click=!click"` instead of `ng-click="click!=click"`.

Also your `$scope.click` should not be a primitive type object as your `ng-repeat` section would maintain its own copy of click variable which would not be available to outer html.See [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).

You must use your ng-init directive to initialize click like `ng-init="items=['item 1','item 2'];obj={click:false}"`.

Then use `ng-click="obj.click=!obj.click"` and `ng-class="{show:obj.click}"`.

Here's a working [plunker](http://jsfiddle.net/uLujthsp/19/).

Comment: thanks a lot @Abdul23 .. what if i dont have ng-init ? can i still get the outupt with ng-click="click=!click" ?

Comment: It will work as long as you use `click` variable within the same html element upon which `ng-repeat` was defined. You will have to use wrapper `obj` with ng-init or define it in your controller like`$scope.obj=..` to use it outside the container html element.

Answer (score 0):

see this example :http://jsfiddle.net/uLujthsp/18/

```
<div data-ng-app="" ng-init="names=['Jani','Hege','Kai']">
  <p>Looping with ng-repeat:</p>
  <ul ng-click="click =! click">
    <li ng-repeat="x in names" >
      {{ x }}
    </li>
  </ul>
{{click}}
  <div  ng-show="click">Showing</div>  
</div>
```